# Pass params to transform function of Transformer class in split Transformer class

Tags: craft3, plugin-elementapi, yii

I have transformer like down below in the element API.

```
'transformer' => 'MyTransformerClassName',
```

Or

```
'transformer' => new MyTransformerClassName(),
```

I am going to pass a param like `$user` through `MyTransformerClassName` to use in separate Class Like here.

```
class MyTransformerClassName extends TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Entry $entry)
    {
        return [
            // ... here want to use $user coming from element api
        ];
    }
}
```

How can I pass the `$user` variable to the separate transformer class to use it in transform method?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you would do that...

1. Pass your parameter to the class:

```php
'transformer' => new MyTransformerClassName($user),
```

2. Use a [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) to save it as a [property](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

```php
class MyTransformerClassName extends TransformerAbstract
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function transform(Entry $entry) ...
}
```

3. Use your property as needed:

```php
class MyTransformerClassName extends TransformerAbstract
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct($user) ...


    public function transform(Entry $entry)
    {
        return [
            'user' => $this->user,
            ...
        ];
    }
}
```